# git pull not merging when using a refspec

Tags: git

I'm dealing with a small automation (CI) to synchronise some specific branches between two git repositories.

I need to sync a branch with other using a user-given refspec. e.g.

```
git pull origin "refs/heads/branchOrigin:refs/heads/branchDestination".
```

When the branch can be fast-forwarded there is no problem, but I cannot manage to make it work when it cant. I get "*[rejected] ...... (non-fast forward).*"

I've tried setting *pull.rebase=false* to the config and adding *--no-rebase* to the pull command but the result is the same.

It does work if I just pass the branch names (`git pull origin myBranch --no-edit`) in the same conditions.

I thought about doing fetch+merge, but merge does not accept a refspec parameter so Im not sure how to make this work from a refspec.

any ideas on making git merge the branches on this case?

Comment: What is the rest of the error message?

Comment: nothing.

From ssh://redacted/redactedAgain/moreRedacted
 ! [rejected]              branch1  -> branch2  (non-fast-forward)

Comment: are the branches supposed to be _the same_ in terms of history/contents?

Comment: What is the name of the branch that you have checked out? Is it `branchDestination`?

Comment: @eftshift0 the branch are related. there might be a couple of extra commits on either side. what I want is for them to be merged (assuming there are no conflicts)

Comment: @j6t yes. the local repository is currently on branchDestimation

Comment: All is working as expected. `git pull origin x:y` is legal only if a fast-forward is possible. You need to be on `branchDestination` _and_ you need to say `git pull origin branchOrigin` (or, if `branchOrigin` is already set as the upstream, you could say simply `git pull`).